# CSS - Media Query not functioning correctly

Tags: html, css, media-queries

In my project, I have a div which I want to move the position of when the screen reaches a certain size. I attempt to make a media query to perform this, however the form still stays in one position no matter what screen size.

**Here is my code:**

```css
.formContainer {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 550px;
  margin-left: 768px;
  margin-top: 140px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .formContainer {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="formContainer">
  ....
</div>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="formContainer">
 ....
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.formContainer {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 550px;
  margin-left: 768px;
  margin-top: 140px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .formContainer {
      left: 10px;
    }
  }
```

UPDATED:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .formContainer {
      left: -10000px;
    }
  }
```

UPDATE 2:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .formContainer {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
```

THE CODE:

```
<div class="formContainer">
  <div class="innerContainer">
  </div>

  <img class="test233" src="{% static 'mosque.png' %}" width="70px" style="position: relative; top: -75px; left: 60px;">
  <span style="position: relative; top: -60px; left: 60px; font-size: 32px; font-family: serif;" class="innerText"> Islamagram </span>

    <h2 style="position: relative; font-size: 21px;left:62px; font-family: sans-serif; color: #999999; top: -46px;">&nbsp;Sign up to view and share<br>life-changing islamic content.</h2>

  <form class="form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
      {{ field  }}
      <br>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit"class="btn btn-primary subButton"><span class="signupText">Sign Up</span></button>
  </form>
  {% if error1 %}
    <span style="position: relative; color: red; font-size: 18px; left: 69px; top: 10px;">{{  error1 }}<span>
  {% endif %}
  {% if error2 %}
    <span style="position: relative; color: red; font-size: 18px; left: 68px; top: 10px;">{{  error2 }}</span>
  {% endif %}
  {% if error3 %}
    <span style="position: relative; color: red; font-size: 18px; left: 118px; top: 10px;">{{  error3 }}</span>
  {% endif %}
  {% if error4 %}
    <span  style="position: relative; color: red; font-size: 18px; left: 84px; top: 10px;">{{  error4 }}</span>
  {% endif %}
```

Does anybody know the issue? Thank you.

Comment: The media query is working. The `left: 10px` are applied. Tested your code on codepen. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @epanalepsis Hi! I expect the form to move 10px to the right

Comment: @epanalepsis Check my updated code.

Comment: @epanalepsis I have added the <meta name="viewport>" line as mentioned below, but when I change the value to something mad as shown in updated original post, the div stays the same.

Comment: And you've set your browser's width below 1200px?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, I use Firefox responsive web design tools to set the width to 1200px.

Comment: It has to be *below* 1200px. Like 1199px (or less)...

Comment: Ahhh so you're problem is about the left value which isn't rendered instead of the media query? Because if you'd change the `left: -10000px;` to `background-color: red;` or smth similar it is working pretty well.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes I have set to even lower like 990px, however still same thing occurs.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't think the media query is working. I attempt to change background colour but it stays white when I change screen size to 1199px.

Comment: I added a Stack Snippet to your question, and if you click Run code snippet, you can see it working... the background is red.

Comment: @epanalepsis Hello, It works it Codepen. When I resize my browser to a really small size, still nothing happens.

Comment: @epanalepsis Honestly I do not know the issue. I am resizing the window.

Comment: What browser do you use? It should work. You can check if your browser supports media query here: http://w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: @epanalepsis Chrome. I also tested in mozilla. Same result occurs

Comment: @epanalepsis Just to mention, there are nested elements inside this DIV. Like images etc which all have their position set to relative. Does this make a difference?

Comment: And the above code is all you have? Because otherwise something else that's not in the question is causing the problem, and obviously we can't help you with something we don't know about. Try removing code until the problem goes away, then add code back in. See [mre] for more.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I hightly doubt it. Look at my original post update. I have added all the html inside my Div. Can you spot the issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
.formContainer {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 550px;
  margin-left: 768px;
  margin-top: 140px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .formContainer {
      left: -200px;
    }
  }
```

Comment: @eweee Just comment margin-left and margin-top, in order to media query to work properly.

Comment: Hello, This solution (commenting margins out) also doesn't work.

Comment: @AnshulChaurasia Please [edit] your answer and put the explanation in the answer. Please also explain why changing the margins would affect the applicability of the positioning.

Comment: @eweee make left : 100px to see the effect, while both the margins should be commented.

Comment: @AnshulChaurasia Yes I have. Check my updated code to see whether the issue maybe something else within my Div? Thank you.

Comment: @eweee - try my edited code it should work as you want, also note that below resize 1200  will only give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in your header

Comment: before or after the css?

Comment: Before the css I add it.

Comment: try using some other properties, just to test it, and also try to add !important just before ';'

Comment: I have added the important line and some additional properties however still no change occurs